# How to keep text selected when using React Quill

Tags: reactjs, quill

I'm using the ReactQuill library to build a basic text editor. I have a problem where when I click off of the editor, the text that is selected loses its selection.

When I click a button on the toolbar, it stays selected, but when I click a custom button I've built, the selection is gone. This behavior isn't consistent with for example, Google Docs, where when you click a button on the side to add a comment for example, the text stays selected.

How could I accomplish the same using ReactQuill?

For context, the reason for this is that I have buttons on the side, that when clicked, need to interact with the editor's selected text, but can't, because when they're clicked, the editor loses its selected range.